# Adding extra column to SQL SELECT query output depending on current table and each separate row

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Let's say I have the following table with these rows already inserted:

```
|  a  |   b   |      c      |
|---  |----   |-------      |
| 1A  |  1B   | (null)      |
| 2A  |  2B   |     1A      |
| 3A  |  3B   |     1A      |
```

I would now like to

- `SELECT` everything from the table in a query and
- also count for each row how often `a` of the respectively row appears in `c` in the whole table.

This is what the expected output should look like:

```
|  a  |   b   |      c      | count     |
|---  |----   |-------      |------     |
| 1A  |  1B   | (null)      |     2     |
| 2A  |  2B   |     1A      |     0     |
| 3A  |  3B   |     1A      |     0     |
```

For the first row, "1A" also appears in `c` of the second and third row.
However, "2A" or "3A" doesn't appear anywhere else in `c`.

I've tried the following ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/efa772/18/1)):

```sql
create table test (a varchar(30), b varchar(30), c varchar(30));

insert into test (a, b) values ("1A", "1B");
insert into test (a, b, c) values ("2A", "2B", "1A");
insert into test (a, b, c) values ("3A", "3B", "1A");

select *, (select count(*) from test where test.c = a) as count from test;
```

However, `count` is always `0`.

How can I achieve what I described above in one query? I'd appreciate any help! :)

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. What RDBMS are you *really* using? The fiddle doesn't load either, but you should be including your attempts in the question, not as an offsite resource.

Comment: Tagged with `mysql` based on the SQLFiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) from test t2 where t2.c = t.a)
from test t;
```

This is just like your version but it uses correct table aliases. **Always qualify all column references.**

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT 0 AS Id, 'All' AS Name
>   UNION ALL
>   SELECT Column(s) FROM tableName;

You Can add like this in sql Server.